# Testing strong parameters with shoulda_matchers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, strong-parameters

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to test the strong parameters with rspec and shoulda_matchers.

No matter what I've tried, I always get the message: `RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError: Expected POST #create to restrict parameters on :language_name to :name,
but it did not restrict any parameters.`

This is my controller:

```
class LanguageNamesController < CrudController
  inherit_resources
  actions :all, :except => [:show]

  private
    def language_name_params
      params.require(:language_name).permit(:name)
    end
end
```

This is the test:

```
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe LanguageNamesController, type: :controller do
  describe "parameters" do
    it do
     lm_params = {
       language_name: {
         name: 'John'
       }
     }
     expect(subject).to permit(:name).for(:create, params: { params: lm_params }).on(:language_name)
    end
  end
end
```

Also, I've tried this and got the same result:

```
it do
  subject.params = ActionController::Parameters.new(language_name: {foo: 'bar', name: 'baz'})
  expect(subject).to permit(:name).for(:create).on(:language_name)
end
```

if I try like this, I got `ArgumentError: unknown keyword: language_name`:

```
it do
 lm_params = {
   language_name: {
     name: 'John'
   }
 }
 expect(subject).to permit(:name).for(:create, params: lm_params).on(:language_name)
end
```

I'm using:

- ruby 2.5.1
- rails 5.1.6
- shoulda-matchers 3.1.2

Anyone know how to solve this?

Thank you!

---

This is my workaround to test it:

```
it do
  faker_name = Faker::Name.name

  params = {
    language_name: {name: faker_name, other_attribute: "other value"},
    extra: {extra: 1}
  }
  get :index, params: params

  expect(subject.send(:language_name_params)).to eq({"name"=> faker_name})
end
```

Comment: Or there is another way to test the strong parameters?

Comment: What if you move `language_name_params` to public methods?

Comment: @Vasilisa Per the [Rails documentation](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#methods-and-actions) "It is a best practice to lower the visibility of methods (with private or protected) which are not intended to be actions, like auxiliary methods or filters"

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to create `lm_params`.  Shoulda matchers are going to mock up the params object for you.

If you only need to test the permissions you can do `should permit(:name).for(:create)`

If you need to check for a value on a permitted parameter: `should permit(:name).for(:create, params: {name: 'John'})`

There are good examples in the documentation for [strong_parameters_matcher.rb](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/v2.8.0/lib/shoulda/matchers/action_controller/strong_parameters_matcher.rb)

EDIT: Another good source of documentation is the [rubydoc for shoulda matchers](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/Shoulda%2FMatchers%2FActionController:permit).

Comment: Nice! It worked using this syntax:  expect permit(:name).for(:create).on(:language_name)

Although test is passing now, simplecov is still complaining that there is no test for the strong parameters method (language_name_params). Do you know anything about it?

Thanks!

Comment: Simplecov is not recognizing the method as tested because we are testing the parameters and not the method itself.  I would make a test for one of the controller actions (eg: create), and in that test write an expectation for what `langauge_name_params` should be. I also added some more documentation to the answer that more closely resembles the syntax you have used.